# Restart Gunicorn_django via Fabric

Tags: python, django, fabric, gunicorn

I'm building a Django application and I decided to investigate Fabric for automating deployment. I've got it mostly working, but it fails at the last step, and I can't seem to puzzle out why.

I'm using Nginx and Gunicorn to serve the application, and I want to kill and restart Gunicorn after the changes have been pulled in and the database updated. Unfortunately it always seems to fail at the last hurdle.

The final command doesn't respond with any kind of error, but the application isn't getting served, and if I SSH in there's no process for it and I have to restart it manually. Every other command works perfectly.

My fabfile.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from fabric.api import local, env, run
from fabric.context_managers import cd, prefix

env.hosts = ['192.168.1.1']
env.path = "/home/matthew/Sites/projectname"


def deploy():
    # Push changes to Bitbucket
    local('git push origin master')

    # Switch to project directory
    with cd(env.path):
        # Pull changes to server
        run('git pull origin master')

        # Activate virtualenv
        with prefix('source venv/bin/activate'):

            # Collect static files
            run('python manage.py collectstatic --noinput')

            # Sync and migrate the database
            run('python manage.py syncdb')
            run('python manage.py migrate')

            # Kill and restart Gunicorn
            run('killall gunicorn_django || true')
            run('gunicorn_django -D -c gunicorn.conf.py')
```

If I drop the -D flag so it isn't daemonised, it works and I get the following output, but I have to disconnect manually with Ctrl-C. If I append & to the end, that stops it working:

```
[192.168.1.1] out: 2013-05-22 12:47:51 [60549] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.4
[192.168.1.1] out: 2013-05-22 12:47:51 [60549] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8888 (60549)
[192.168.1.1] out: 2013-05-22 12:47:51 [60549] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[192.168.1.1] out: 2013-05-22 12:47:51 [60554] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 60554
[192.168.1.1] out: 2013-05-22 12:47:51 [60555] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 60555
[192.168.1.1] out: 2013-05-22 12:47:51 [60556] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 60556
[192.168.1.1] out:
```

Can anyone see where I've gone astray?

Comment: When you run it manually, are you doing it from the virtual environment? Also, what do you get if you type `which guinicon_django`? Perhaps the location isn't in the `PATH`.

Comment: I installed Gunicorn into the virtualenv, and when I run it manually via SSH, I've already activated the virtualenv.

Comment: Path looks to be correct - it's /home/matthew/Sites/projectname/venv/bin/gunicorn_django, and gunicorn_django is in the venv/bin/ directory.

Comment: Have you tried to run it without demonising it (-D) so you get the output? Are you perhaps using different user accounts to run it manually vs via fabric?

Comment: @AJJ I've just given that a go, and that works. Only downside is it stays connected, and I have to use Ctrl-C to disconnect. I'll pop the output into the question body.

Comment: Try sticking it in the background with `&` and see if that helps; or barring that use something like [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) or [`circus`](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/0.7/).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Already gave that a go, and that stops it working. It's now working to some extent, but I'll take a look at supervisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't ever resolve this as such, but I finally knuckled down and picked up [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). As it turned out, Supervisor was pretty simple to use and thanks to [this blog post](https://davidpoblador.com/run-django-apps-using-gunicorn-and-nginx/) I was able to puzzle it out quite quickly. Just thought I'd post this in case someone else has the same kind of issue and stumbles across this page.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue too. I waited for few seconds between killing and restarting the gunicorn process and it seems to run fine for now.

```
kill_running_gunicorn_process()
time.sleep(10)
start_gunicorn_process()
```