# fabric kill gunicorn process only if it is running

Tags: python, django, fabric, gunicorn

I am very new to fabric. In my fabric file I want to restart gunicorn. For that I am killing the gunicorn process first and then starting it..

It looks like:

```
def restart_gunicorn():
    run('ps ax|grep gunicorn')
    run('pkill gunicorn')
    run('gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 %(path)s/application/wsgi &' % env)
```

When I run this it gives me error at `pkill gunicorn` because at start i will not have any gunicorn process running. So I want to have a check lik if gunicorn processes are running then only kill gunicorn. If  not gunicorn process are running I just want to start the gunicorn process..

How can I do this ?
Need help. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689873/restart-gunicorn-django-via-fabric

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `settings(warn_only=True)` and will only give you a warning, but the execution won't fail:

```
def restart_gunicorn():
    run('ps ax|grep gunicorn')
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run('pkill gunicorn')
    run('gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 %(path)s/application/wsgi &' % env)
```

More info on `settings` context manager here: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings